# Xbox Party Chat Sample Rate Unsupported

Tags: xbox-network, windows-10

I am on **Windows 10 Pro 10.0.15063 Build 15063** using the **Xbox App** and a **Logitech C525.**

I was starting a party and it said that my microphone sample rate was unsupported. I changed it to every single one I had:

- 1 channel, 16 bit, 48000 Hz
- 1 channel, 16 bit, 32000 Hz
- 1 channel, 16 bit, 16000 Hz

None of them worked. I tried installing the webcam driver and that did nothing. It receives audio in OBS and the sound settings.